# Neo4j Tree structure with stop condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have Neo4j version 3.0.4 with tree based data inside and I am trying to find solution for following problem:

I want start from root and travel down collecting all nodes. When I found node of type (property) "female" I want to include it in the result and stop going down.

[Here is my try to describe the problem and expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yuqvl.png)

Notes:

- there is relationship between nodes called "relation". Every node has
  only 1 parent so it is tree structure.

So far I have:

> match p=(root:User {isRoot:true})-[:RELATION*..]-(child:User) return p

Which return the tree structure but without stopping condition

How can achieve the result?

Update 1:
Maybe a better way to describe the desired outcome is - I want every node from a tree going in depth and starting from root (or specific node) that has no direct or indirect parents of type female. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here, really. The easy one is to do as InverseFalcon suggests and get all results, then prune using a predicate:

```
MATCH (root:User {isRoot: true})
WITH root
MATCH p = (root) - [:RELATION*] -> (:User {type: 'female'} )
WHERE ALL(x IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE x.type = 'male')
RETURN NODES(p)
```

The harder, but better one, especially if your data set is very large or you plan to run a very large number of queries, is to refactor your data model so that instead of a generic `-[:RELATION]->`, you have particular relationship types that you plan to query against (`:DAUGHTER|:SON`, e.g.). Relationships in neo4j are much faster to query on than node labels or especially node properties, so design your relationships to accommodate the analysis you'll want to perform.

Comment: Great that seems to work. I'd like to explore the second option with relations but change the requirements a bit. Lets say that we don't have type but age and if the age is greater then 70 then we stop.

e.g 


`MATCH (root:User {userId:'some-id'})
WITH root
MATCH p = ((root)-[:RELATION*]->(u:User))
WHERE u.age > 0 and ALL(x IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE x.age < 70)
RETURN u.userId`

Can we achieve that with relations and is it better?

Comment: You can achieve pretty much anything by relations, if you define the right relations.

Comment: First example becomes:
`MATCH p = (root) -[:SON*]->()-[:DAUGHTER]->() RETURN LAST(NODES(p))`

Second would be like:
`MATCH p = (root) - [:KNOWS*]->()-[:RESPECTS]->() RETURN LAST(NODES(p))`

The question becomes, is your problem really a good fit for a graph db? The more your problem requires detailed analysis of properties (like age<70), the less elegant a graph solution is gonna be. But if you just need to get the job done, neo4j is fast enough that the pruning queries will get you there.

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED]

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH p=(root:User {isRoot:true})-[:RELATION*0..]-(:User {type: 'male'})-[:RELATION]-(:User {type: 'female'})
RETURN p;
```

This query should return all paths that start at the root node and end at a female node, but without going through any other female nodes. I have assumed that the non-female nodes have "male" as the `type` value. The variable-length relationship pattern specifies `0..` so that a path consisting of a female root node can be returned as well.

Comment: Not really this will filter results by all nodes that have type of female. The goal is to return both male and female and stop going deep when there is female one but still include it.

Check in the image how A2 is male (include), B2 is female (include) and C2 is male but should not be included because B2 is female.

Comment: I don't think the update changes the output much. If there are two occurrences of `(:User{type:'male'})-[:RELATION]-(:User{type:'female'})`, the variable relation will still make this match on both occurrences. I don't think you can cause a variable match to stop like this. I think the most you can do is add a predicate to prune the results that ensures that only one female :User exists in the nodes in the match (excluding the head of the nodes, as the root user may be female)